# Why didn't the Night King try this before?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the last episode of *Game of Thrones* season 7 we saw that the Night King broke the Wall and invaded Eastwatch with all his troops and  White Walkers.

Maybe I haven't caught it, but how could the Night King break the Wall but was not able to do that in the past?

Comment: Wall is magic, dragons are magic,...

Comment: Have you watched the rest of the series?

Comment: The wall was created to defend the realm against the White Walkers and it has, until now.

Comment: ATTENTION!! THE ANSWER BELOW IS WRONG.

Comment: The wall "was supposedly *constructed using* both *magic* and mundane means [...] to defend the realm against the White Walkers"

Comment: https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wall

Comment: It's not mentioned in the series however. The wall had magic spells that only the fire of the dragon could lift. The downvotes are assumed that he couldn't do it. Well the "Free Folk" managed to almost do it, so there would be no problem for the dead to do the same, yet the magic kept them there.

Answer (score 5):

### The Night King only recently obtained a dragon.

In "Beyond the Wall," season 7 episode 6, the Night King kills and then reanimates (white walker-style) Viserion. We see in "The Dragon and the Wolf," season 7 episode 7, the Night King and Viserion bring down that section of wall.

It's not too much of a leap to assume that the Night King *couldn't* bring down the wall before he had a dragon under his control, capable of spewing 50' jets of undead blue fire.